# Dispatch async action

Tags: javascript, vue.js

By changing my action to async I am not able to dispatch it. Whenever I make the dispatch it enters the cath with the value false. Here is my page where I dispatch the action from mounted hook (I tried created too)

```
mounted () {
  this.$store.dispatch('productById', this.$route.params['id']).then((response) => {
    this.product = response
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

And this is my action

```
async productById ({commit}, payload) {
  const AuthStr = await getAdminOrRespondentAuth()
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    commit(PRODUCT_BY_ID)
    axios.get(`${API_BASE}/products/${payload}`, {
      params: {
        origin: '1'
      },
      transformRequest: [function (data, headers) {
        delete headers.common.Authorization
        headers.Authorization = AuthStr
        return data
      }],
      paramsSerializer: params => parseParams(params)
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        commit(PRODUCT_BY_ID_SUCCESS, response.data)
        resolve(response.data)
      } else {
        reject(response)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.response.data.idStatus === 1) {
        commit(PRODUCT_BY_ID_SUCCESS, err.response.data.data)
        reject(err)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

When the Vue enters mounted hook it "dispatch the action" and goes straight into the catch block not calling my action. My action is not executed.

**If I change my action to sync, everything works** normally. I need this action to be async because **getAdminOrRespondentAuth** function thats call oidc async method to recover user.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Can you show `getAdminOrRespondentAuth`? I suspect it may not return a Promise that resolves to a value.

Comment: There's also always the possibility that you simply reject the Promise yourself. In any case, we need more information to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Samurai8 is right. Thanks for the help. My getAdminOrRespondentAuth was not returning a promise correctly. After correcting the error of the function everything came back to work. This is the function that generate error discribed:

```
async function getAdminOrRespondentAuth () {
  let mgr = new Mgr()
  var adminToken = await mgr.getToken()
  if (adminToken !== false) {
    return 'Bearer '.concat(adminToken)
  } else {
    let usrToken = localStorage.getItem('user-token')
    return 'Bearer '.concat(usrToken)
  }
}
```

Here is the function that works:

```
async function getAdminOrRespondentAuth () {
  var adminToken = ''
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let mgr = new Mgr()
    try {
      adminToken = await mgr.getToken()
    } catch (error) {
      adminToken = error
    }
    if (adminToken !== false) {
      resolve('Bearer '.concat(adminToken))
    } else {
      let usrToken = localStorage.getItem('user-token')
      if (usrToken !== null) {
        resolve('Bearer '.concat(usrToken))
      } else {
        resolve('')
      }
    }
  })
}
```